# Magento 1 : Adminhtml block not called in my custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, custom

I created a module to show the customer inquiries on product in admin grid.
From controller it is not directed to my block.Below is my code.

**Config.xml**

```
<config>
.....
<global>
    <blocks>
        <eight25media_requestquote>
            <class>Eight25media_Requestquote_Block</class>
        </eight25media_requestquote>
    </blocks>
..................
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <requestquote>Eight25media_Requestquote_Adminhtml</requestquote>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
..........
</config>
```

**adminhtml.xml**

```
<config>
<menu>
    <requestquote translate="title" module="requestquote">
        <title>Quotes</title>
        <sort_order>71</sort_order>
        <children>
            <quotemenus translate="title" module="requestquote">
                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                <title>Manage Quotes</title>
                <action>adminhtml/quotes/</action>
            </quotemenus>
        </children>
    </requestquote>
</menu>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <requestquote>
                    <title>Quotes</title>
                    <sort_order>60</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <quotemenus translate="title">
                            <title>Manage Quotes</title>
                        </quotemenus>
                    </children>
                </requestquote>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

**QuotesController.php**

```
class Eight25media_Requestquote_Adminhtml_QuotesController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action
{

    protected function _initAction()
    {
       $this->loadLayout();

       return $this;

     }    

     public function indexAction() {

        $this->_title($this->__('Quotes'))->_title($this->__('Manage Quotes'));
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('requestquote/quotemenus');
        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('requestquote/adminhtml_quotes'));
        $this->renderLayout();
     }
```

**Block File : Quotes.php**

```
<?php
class Eight25media_Requestquote_Block_Adminhtml_Quotes extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
public function __construct(){  

    $this->_blockGroup = 'requestquote';
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_quotes';        
    $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('requestquote')->__('Product Quote Collection');

    parent::__construct();
}
}
```

If i echo some thing in my block file nothing show and i am unable to access to my block file.What is the mistake i am doing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your config.xml you have to change

```
->createBlock('requestquote/adminhtml_quotes')
```

to

```
->createBlock('eight25media_requestquote/adminhtml_quotes')
```

Or you change the definition of `global/blocks` to `requestquote` instead of `eight25media_requestquote`.

Comment: Yes this was the issue and I corrected in the same way.thank you.